# Open file and set its contents to a TextArea in JavaFX NullPointer

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am building a small editor app in JavaFX and I am doing it with FXML file and controllers. I have several FXML files (each with its corresponding controller). All I am trying to do is handle a 'open file' operation from the 'root' fxml (which contains a `MenuBar`) and then pass that file to the other controller, which should 'parse' it and then display it in the designated `TextArea`. But I get a `NullPointerException` and I cannot figure it out. Debugging did not help me either.

Here is some of my code:

First, a method from my `RootLayout.fxml`, which contains the menu item to open a file:

```
@FXML
private void handleOpen() {
    fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("."));
    extFilter1 = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML Documents (*.xml)", "*.xml");
    extFilter2 = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilter1, extFilter2);

    xmlFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());

    if(xmlFile != null) {
       EditorOverviewController controller = new EditorOverviewController();
        try {
            controller.loadXmlFile(xmlFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RootLayoutController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `loadXmlFile` method in the other controller:

```
public void loadXmlFile(File file) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            sb.append((char) bis.read());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        sourceEditor.setText(sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RootLayoutController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Where `sourceEditor` is my `fx:id` of the text area, which is annotated at the top of the controller as normal:

```
@FXML
private TextArea sourceEditor;
```

And I get this `NullPointer` at:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mainApp.view.EditorOverviewController.loadXmlFile(EditorOverviewController.java:103)
    at uimlbuddy.view.RootLayoutController.handleOpen(RootLayoutController.java:81)
```

Any clues as to what exactly am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I am loading my fxml files and getting the controllers like this in my MainApp class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/assets/app_icon.png"));

    initRootLayout();

    showEditorOverview();
}

 /**
 * Initializes the root layout.
 */
private void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the editor overview with all panels inside the root layout.
 */
private void showEditorOverview() {
    try {
        // Load person overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/EditorOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane editorOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Set editor overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(editorOverview);

        EditorOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then in each controller I have this method `setMainApp` to give a reference back to itself:

```
/**
 * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
 *
 * @param mainApp
 */
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp= mainApp;
}
```

Comment: Why `EditorOverviewController controller = new EditorOverviewController();` ?

Comment: Because the `handleOpen()` method is in the `RootLayoutController`, while the actual 'opening' is in the `EditorOverviewController`.

Comment: But you're creating a **new** `EditorOverviewController`, instead of using the one the `FXMLLoader` created (and initialized). There is no way the `FXMLLoader` can inject the `@FXML`-annotated fields into this new controller. You need to use the one you get from the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: So I need to move my `loadXmlFile()` to the `MainApp` class where I have the `FXMLLoader`? How would I be able to access the `@FXML TextArea` from there? I am not sure I completely understand...

Comment: No, there's no need to do that. See answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose a property in the `RootLayoutController` (I am assuming this is the controller with the `handleOpen()` method) to hold the selected file:

```
public class RootLayoutController {

    private final ObjectProperty<File> selectedFile = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "selectedFile");
    public final ObjectProperty<File> selectedFileProperty() {
        return selectedFile ;
    }
    public final File getSelectedFile() {
        return selectedFile.get();
    }
    public final void setSelectedFile(File file) {
        this.selectedFile.set(file);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleOpen() {
        fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("."));
        extFilter1 = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML Documents (*.xml)", "*.xml");
        extFilter2 = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilter1, extFilter2);

        xmlFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());

        if (xmlFile != null) {
            setSelectedFile(xmlFile);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then in your main app you can observe that property and update the other controller when it changes:

```
private void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();

        // really should not need this ugly coupling from your controllers back to the app
        // controller.setMainApp(this);

        controller.selectedFileProperty().addListener((obs, oldFile, newFile) -> {
            if (newFile != null) {
                editorOverviewController.loadXmlFile(newFile);
            }
        }

        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You obviously need `editorOverviewController` to be an instance field in your main app, which can be initialized in the `showEditorOverview` method:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    private EditorOverviewController editorOverviewController ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // as before ...
    }

    private void initRootLayout() {
        // as above ...
    }

    private void showEditorOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/EditorOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane editorOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set editor overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(editorOverview);

            // note subtle change here:
            this.editorOverviewController = loader.getController();

            // again, should not need this:
            // controller.setMainApp(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried that, and at first I got another NullPointer when I hit the `handleOpen()` method. I had to remove the `showOpenDialog(mainApp.getPrimaryStage())` and leave it to just `showOpenDialog(null);` not to get that NullPointer. Now it works. Thanks again! Got a new level of understanding of how that FXMLLoader works.

Comment: You can do `showOpenDialog(anyNode.getScene().getWindow());` where `anyNode` is any node displayed in the scene. I would get rid of the `mainApp` field entirely in the controllers.

Comment: What's the idea though? It seems to work without specifying any node from the scene. Is there an advantage to this?

Comment: The `FileChooser` is a dialog window, so it makes sense for it to have an "owning" window. This makes sure that the correct window becomes active when you dismiss the file chooser, and that it [blocks input to that window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) when showing. It probably works fine without, but it's good practice (imho) to specify the owning window when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You must load the second FXML and then extract the controller from it. Use :

```
FXMLoader loader = new FXMLoader(path to your fxml);
loader.load();
EditorOverviewController controller = (EditorOverviewController)loader.getController();
```

Comment: I am doing something similar. Check my updated question, please.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with all the controllers but you need a reference of `EditorOverviewController` that you had obtained while loading the controller inside your `handleOpen()` inorder to get an initialized `TextArea`